# Не могу подключить CSS к HTML

Tags: html, css

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatibe" content="ie=edge">
    <title>QBook</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css01/mainpage.css" type="text/css"/>
</head>
```

Получается файл `mainpage.html` находится в папке проекта, там же есть папка `assets` в нем.

Папка `css01` и `imgs`, но когда хочу взять файлы с этих папок - `html` почему-то их не видит.

Но если все файлы (`.css`, `.png`) находятся с `.html` в одной папке - они друг друга видят.

Comment: А как вы "берете" файлы из этих папок?

Comment: попробуйте так: href="./assets/css01/mainpage.css" (после открывающей кавычки точка)

Comment: Браузер берёт файлы по URL, а не по папкам на диске. У сервера может быть какая угодно конфигурация адресов, даже совсем не похожая на структуру папок.

Comment: @Academik                                                                                                              
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css01/mainpage.css" type="text/css"/>                       Наподобие этого просто обращаюсь

Comment: @АндрійПанчій Заработала спасибо большое!

Comment: @PavelGrishaev А окококок

Answer (score 2):

Просто добавьте точку (.) в начало или уберите слеш (/)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css01/mainpage.css" type="text/css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css01/mainpage.css" type="text/css"/>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Все заработала)